# convert array values to object, add keys based on index position

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, underscore.js

I'm using a data source in a handlebars template. When I fetch the data the resulting object contains nested arrays like:

```
["10004", "Some title", "Some Description", "$19.95", "Some other text here..."]
```

I want to convert the array values to objects and set/access the object keys  (this is for inclusion on handlebars template). any advice helpful. ty!

for more info: this is what I have constructed so far.

```
// data from API http response is var data

let dataObj = {};
    dataObj =
      _.chain(data)
      .values()
      .map(function(el){
        return {'product': el};
      });
```

my result is like so:

```
{"products": [
     {
         "product":[
            "123456",
            "Some title",
            "Some descritpion.Lorem ipsum"
         ]
      }
]};
```

but what I'm looking for is:

```
{
   "products":[
      {
         "product":[
            {
               "id":"123456"
            },
            {
               "title":"Some title"
            },
            {
               "description":"Some descritpion.Lorem ipsum"
            },
            {
               "price":"$103.05"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

edit: thanks again for dropping by!

Comment: The format you're looking for seems incredibly contrived and unnatural to use. Wouldn't something like [this](https://pastebin.com/DFnEBh1t) be a lot better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can create a simple convert function and reuse it.

```
function convert(data){
       return {
          product: [{
             id: data[0],
             title: data[1],
             description: data[2],
             price: data[3]
          }]
       }
    }
```

```js
let data = ["10004", "Some title", "Some Description", "$19.95", "Some other text here..."];

function convert(data){
   return {
      product: [{
         id: data[0],
         title: data[1],
         description: data[2],
         price: data[3]
      }]
   }
}

console.log(convert(data))
```

Comment: perfect thanks, I was able to add to the chained map fn.